# Change checkbox to checked based on Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object and I want to loop through it and then change associated checkboxes to checked if the key value matches the input value. Here's what I've tried:

```js
var object = {
  opt1:"Red Large",
  opt2:"Orange Medium",
  opt3: "Green Small"
};

$.each(object, function (k, v) {
  console.log(v);
  $('input[value="' + v + ']"').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input value="Blue XL" type="checkbox" /> Blue XL</label>
<label><input value="Red Large" type="checkbox" /> Red Large</label>
<label><input value="Orange Medium" type="checkbox" /> Orange Medium</label>
<label><input value="Green Small" type="checkbox" /> Green Small</label>
```

In this example, I would want `Red`, `Orange` and `Green` checkboxes to be checked, while `Blue` would remain unchecked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `"` in the wrong place. It needs to be within the `]` to look like this:

```
$('input[value="' + v + '"]')
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var object = {
  opt1:"Red Large",
  opt2:"Orange Medium",
  opt3: "Green Small"
};

$.each(object, function (k, v) {
  console.log(v);
  $('input[value="' + v + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input value="Blue XL" type="checkbox" /> Blue XL</label>
<label><input value="Red Large" type="checkbox" /> Red Large</label>
<label><input value="Orange Medium" type="checkbox" /> Orange Medium</label>
<label><input value="Green Small" type="checkbox" /> Green Small</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `forEach` loop on `Object.values` and template literals for selector.

```js
var object = {opt1:"Red Large",opt2:"Orange Medium",opt3: "Green Small"};
Object.values(object).forEach(v => $(`input[value="${v}"]`).attr('checked', true));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input value="Blue XL" type="checkbox" /> Blue XL</label>
<label><input value="Red Large" type="checkbox" /> Red Large</label>
<label><input value="Orange Medium" type="checkbox" /> Orange Medium</label>
<label><input value="Green Small" type="checkbox" /> Green Small</label>
```

Or with plain js.

```js
var object = {opt1:"Red Large",opt2:"Orange Medium",opt3: "Green Small"};
Object.values(object).forEach(v => {
  document.querySelector(`input[value="${v}"]`).checked = true
});
```

```html
<label><input value="Blue XL" type="checkbox" /> Blue XL</label>
<label><input value="Red Large" type="checkbox" /> Red Large</label>
<label><input value="Orange Medium" type="checkbox" /> Orange Medium</label>
<label><input value="Green Small" type="checkbox" /> Green Small</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to make your object an iterable then iterate using `for...of` and use `document.querySelector` to set the `checked` property of desired elements.

```js
function makeIterable(o) {
  o[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    var values = Object.values(o);
    return {
      next() {
        var done = values.length === 0;
        var value = values.shift();
        return {
          done,
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
var obj = {
  opt1: "Red Large",
  opt2: "Orange Medium",
  opt3: "Green Small"
};

makeIterable(obj);

for (var val of obj) {
  document.querySelector(`[value='${val}']`).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<label><input value="Blue XL" type="checkbox" /> Blue XL</label>
<label><input value="Red Large" type="checkbox" /> Red Large</label>
<label><input value="Orange Medium" type="checkbox" /> Orange Medium</label>
<label><input value="Green Small" type="checkbox" /> Green Small</label>
```